# Create password protected ZIP file in PHP

Tags: php

Hi  i am Using Following Code For create password protected zip file

```
$password = 'pass';
$outfile = 'download.zip';    
$infile = 'xml.php';    
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");   
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$outfile");    
@system("zip -P $password $outfile $infile");    
readfile($outfile);    
@unlink($outfile);
```

but it is not working.

Comment: what error its showing.?

Comment: Stop muting errors. In development environment display them directly, when released log them. I.e. remove `@` in front of functions and enable error reporting.

Comment: @Amol Maske: are you sure you are using the free version of zip?

Comment: Actually, download.zip is getting created but when trying to open that zip file it says "Can not open file as archive"

Comment: Did you try to leave the UNLINK away? There is a high chance that the file gets deleted too early.

Comment: @uncovery: unlikely the unlink is the cause of the problem. php functions are blocking: by the unlink() is reached, readfile() would have completed

Answer (score 1):

Same code is working for me. When i first ran this, i got permission error, when i gave the permission to folder, it worked. You can also check for folder permissions. It might also work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your example is dumbed down and the password comes from somewhere else (maybe user input?), the system call is not safe! If it contains characters that have meaning to the shell, you'll get undesired result. Make sure you escape parameters with escapeshellarg: http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php